# How i can determine when a process id (PID) is 32 or 64 bit application?

Tags: delphi, winapi

I need determine when a process id (PID) is 32 or 64 bit application using delphi, how i can do that? I really check the [`IsWow64Process`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms684139%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) function but works with a process handle not a PID.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You can use the [`OpenProcess`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms684320%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) function to get a handle to the pid and then call the [`IsWow64Process`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms684139%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) function.

Remember that you must load the [`IsWow64Process`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms684139%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) function using the [`GetProcAddress`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms683212%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) function because some versions of Windows does not include this function.

Check this sample code

```
{$APPTYPE CONSOLE}

uses
  Windows,
  SysUtils;

type
  TIsWow64Process = function(Handle:THandle; var IsWow64 : BOOL) : BOOL; stdcall;
var
  IsWow64Process  : TIsWow64Process;

procedure Init_IsWow64Process;
var
  hKernel32      : Integer;
begin
  hKernel32 := LoadLibrary(kernel32);
  if (hKernel32 = 0) then RaiseLastOSError;
  try
    IsWow64Process := GetProcAddress(hkernel32, 'IsWow64Process');
  finally
    FreeLibrary(hKernel32);
  end;
end;

function PidIs64BitsProcess(dwProcessId: DWORD): Boolean;
var
  IsWow64        : BOOL;
  PidHandle      : THandle;
begin
  Result := False;
  if Assigned(IsWow64Process) then
  begin
    //check if the current app is running under WOW
    if IsWow64Process(GetCurrentProcess(), IsWow64) then
      Result := IsWow64
    else
      RaiseLastOSError;

    //the current delphi App is not running under wow64, so the current Window OS is 32 bit
    //and obviously all the apps are 32 bits.
    if not Result then Exit;

    PidHandle := OpenProcess(PROCESS_QUERY_INFORMATION,False,dwProcessId);
    if PidHandle > 0 then
    try
      if (IsWow64Process(PidHandle, IsWow64)) then
        Result := not IsWow64
      else
        RaiseLastOSError;
    finally
      CloseHandle(PidHandle);
    end;
  end;
end;


begin
  try
    Init_IsWow64Process;
    //here pass the pid which you want to check
    Writeln(BoolToStr(PidIs64BitsProcess(1940),True));
  except
    on E:Exception do
      Writeln(E.Classname, ': ', E.Message);
  end;
  Readln;
end.
```

Comment: But, If this code compiled under 64bit Delphi, this is have incorrect result. "IsWow64 from IsWow64Process: If the process is a 64-bit application running under 64-bit Windows, the value is also set to FALSE." And we get always False from 64 bit process

Answer (score -1):

if you are checking for the app itself:

```
{$IFDEF WIN32}
    ShowMessage('32-bit App itself');
{$ENDIF}
{$IFDEF WIN64}
    ShowMessage('64-bit App itself');
{$ENDIF}
```